# Does OpenEBS supports NFS volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, nfs, openebs

Does OpenEBS support NFS for shared storage? Or do you have any other options to use OpenEBS jiva volume for NFS kind of storage options?

Answer (score 3):

People are using NFS on top of OpenEBS for wordpress and similar.  An OpenEBS engineer explains one approach here:  https://blog.openebs.io/setting-up-persistent-volumes-in-rwx-mode-using-openebs-142632244cb2